# Geração de arquivos com caractere inválido

Tags: c#

Desenvolvi o código abaixo para colocar informações de um retorno de um select do banco em um arquivo CSV, entretanto como podem ver em print em anexo, alguns caracteres estão sendo enviados errados mesmo que o retorno do select está correto, de que forma eu poderia colocar um UTF-8 ou outros charset. Uma coisa interessante que também não entendi o que ocorreu é que numeros grandes estão vindo errados na exibição mas quando eu clico neles em cima aparece o numero corretamente.

P.s a parte comentada foi algo que eu tentei utilizar porem não obtive sucesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
                    List<RemessaArquivo> Dados = bll.Dados(ID);

                    System.Text.StringBuilder ConteudoArq = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    System.Text.StringBuilder ConteudoLin = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

                    //Matriz para criar todas as linhas e colunas com os dados
                    Dados.ForEach(x =>
                    {
                        // uso do reflection nas linhas
                        Type type = typeof(RemessaArquivo);
                        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
                        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                        {
                            ConteudoLinha.Append(property.GetValue(x, null) + ";");

                        }
                        ConteudoArquivo.AppendLine(ConteudoLin.ToString());
                        ConteudoLinha.Clear();
                    });
                    /* string auxConversao = "";
                     byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ConteudoArquivo.ToString());
                     auxConversao = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                     */

                    //Definindo onde o arquivo será gerado
                    using (System.IO.StreamWriter arquivoCSV = new StreamWriter(@"C:\ArquivosRemessa\arquivo.csv", false))
                    {
                        arquivoCSV.WriteLine(ConteudoArq.ToString());
                        arquivoCSV.Close();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, Matheus

Você já tentou setar o encoding que deseja?
na linha abaixo:

```
   using (System.IO.StreamWriter arquivoCSV = new StreamWriter(@"C:\ArquivosRemessa\arquivo.csv", false))
```

Utilize:

```
   using (System.IO.StreamWriter arquivoCSV = new StreamWriter(@"C:\ArquivosRemessa\arquivo.csv", false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
```

Ou mesmo o System.Text.Encoding.Default

Espero que tenha te ajudado.

Att

Comment: Ja tentei sim, eu tenho o seguinte retorno de erro:

Comment: Error 57 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Text.Encoding' to 'bool'

Comment: Com base no que você me disse, pensei em enviar o false entre os 2 parametros, editei sua pergunta, muito obrigado, os dados estão vindo corretamente!